# QNAP TS-239 Pro Not Booting

Tags: qnap

My QNAP TS-239 Pro, and which I have had for more than two years seamlessly running, is no longer visible on the network; when I switch it off and on the power green button is not lit and the fan is constantly exceptionally loud. I pressed the reset button but nothing happens (normally it would beep after 3 seconds and again after 10 seconds - It doesn't at all)

Reboot doesn't help and funny enough no indication the device is on except for the louder sound of its fan.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that my previous post has been deleted by some eager admin, here's another one:

I had the same problem, but have just found a solution. I've pressed the reset button (the one that needs to be pressed with a pencil or so) on the NAS for a few seconds.

Apart from resetting the admin password it also resets/clears the network settings on the NAS.

This did the job for me, afterwards I could access it again, and even after another reboot it still works.

I hope that solves your problem, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you reset the NAS at the backside with a pin indeed the password will be default admin, and the DHCP will be activated, means the NAS becomes an IP from the router. If problem persists, try to reboot without disks in the NAS. When  first beep is not coming it's a hardware issue.When the NAS starts up without disks you can check with Qfinder if it's get detected. If so insert the disks and reboot again. When  not starting up it's or the first disk /dev/sda what's causing this or the backplane/motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth I had exactly the same issue - specifically, TS-239 Pro II+ running happily for ages then there was a power outage and it refused to come back to life when the power was restored to the house. Just the fan running incredibly loudly and no drive lights. The fix? I disconnected the USB drive that was plugged into it, and then rebooted the qnap. It then happily started up like normal. I suspect it was trying to boot from the external USB drive!